# Как расширить фон в HTML, CSS?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Хотелось бы расширить фон, не знаю как это сделать. Все элементы уходят под серый фон, в неизвестность. Заранее извиняюсь за свою криворукость, я - новичок.
[image: Хочу расширить фон][фон]

```
#central-container {
padding-top: 20px;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
background-image: url("file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/Заготовка/img/central-bg-top.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
}
```